# Futamura Projections- Compatibility - Interpreter and Compiler

Tags: computability

I've just learnt a week ago in my compatibility class about fotomora. These are three rules/tricks you can do with interpreter and compiler.

I'm looking for a bit more information about the subject and I can't find anything in google.

Do anyone knows this topic? Do anyone know where can I read further regarding this topic?

Thank you all.

Comment: Never heard of it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just want to tell you I found the answer to my question and by that closing this topic.

I've spelled the name of the inventor incorrect - the correct name is "Futamura".

Basic information on this topic can be found at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_evaluation

Also there is a nice explained topic in stackoverflow : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637278/building-your-own-interpreter-that-can-function-as-a-compiler

And at last if you are really intrested on this topic, there is very nice article at the following link : http://blog.sigfpe.com/2009/05/three-projections-of-doctor-futamura.html

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your third link is the same as your second link. Mistake?

Comment: Yes. thank you. fixed.